# Firebase + firestore error by login

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have created a login system with `firebase` and `firestore` but if I want to login or sign up, this error occurs:

[image]

I've removed some code, but it does not work

signup code:

```
    signup() {
       this.performingRequest = true

       fb.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.signupForm.email, this.signupForm.password).then(user => {
        this.$store.commit('setCurrentUser', user)

                // create user obj
                fb.usersCollection.doc(user.uid).set({
                  name: this.signupForm.name,
                  email: this.signupForm.email
                }).then(() => {
                    this.$store.dispatch('fetchUserProfile')
                    this.performingRequest = false
                    this.$router.push('/world')
                }).catch(err => {
                    console.log(err)
                    this.performingRequest = false
                    this.errorMsg = err.message
                })
            }).catch(err => {
                console.log(err)
                this.performingRequest = false
                this.errorMsg = err.message
            })
        },
```

Error:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()` method returns a `UserCredential` as explained in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#createUserWithEmailAndPassword). The [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth#.UserCredential) for the `UserCredential` explains that it contains, among others, a `User` object.

So you should do as follows.

```
signup() {
       this.performingRequest = true

       fb.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.signupForm.email, this.signupForm.password).then(userCredential => {
        this.$store.commit('setCurrentUser', userCredential.user) //Or userCredential, depending on what you want to save.

                // create user obj
                fb.usersCollection.doc(userCredential.user.uid).set({
                  name: this.signupForm.name,
                  email: this.signupForm.email
                }).then(() => {
                    this.$store.dispatch('fetchUserProfile')
                    this.performingRequest = false
                    this.$router.push('/world')
                }).catch(err => {
                    console.log(err)
                    this.performingRequest = false
                    this.errorMsg = err.message
                })
            }).catch(err => {
                console.log(err)
                this.performingRequest = false
                this.errorMsg = err.message
            })
        },
```

Comment: The error seems to be thrown by the `set()` method and not because `fb.usersCollection.doc(userCredential.user.uid)` is a wrong document reference. You should double check the values you pass to `set()`

Answer (score 0):

convert user.uid to String :

```
fb.usersCollection.doc(String(user.uid))
```